# Where is tf.distributions in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: tensorflow2.0

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Distribution

There is no doc on this?

I see the doc on contrib but nothing about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been moved into [Tensorflow Probability (TFP)](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability):

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-probability
```

Comment: Is this supposed to work in tf 2.0? I see it uses contrib which no longer exists so I get errors on import.

Comment: Installing from latest master seems to be ok.

Comment: yes it is supposed to work with tf2 - however, if my answer solved your problem please remember to mark it as accepted!

Comment: This is correct, but the current stable release of TFP (pip package `tensorflow-probability`) is only compatible with TF release version 1.13.1. To use TFP with the TF 2.0 series, you'll currently need to use our nightly build (pip package `tfp-nightly`). This *should* work with 2.0 alpha (`tensorflow==2.0.0a0`) but will definitely work with 2.0 nightly (`tf-nightly-2.0-preview`)